# How to make a QMdiArea subwindow widget non-resizeable?

Tags: c++, qt, qmdiarea

So the non-`QMdiArea` version of my code,

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget* parent)
{
   ...
   layout()->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetFixedSize );
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(...)
{
   ...
   MyWidget* wgt = new MyWidget(NULL);
   wgt->show();
}
```

works just fine and produces a widget that the user can't resize.  But when the `MainWindow` code is replaced with

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(...)
{
   ...
   MyWidget* wgt = new MyWidget(ui->mdiArea); //Or MyWidget(NULL), same result
   ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(wgt);
}
```

the window, now within the `QMdiArea`, is resizeable.  It doesn't seem to be an issue of Qt::WindowFlags, they don't handle resize policy.  Surely there is a way to do this?  NB I cant use something like `setFixedSize(ht, wd)` since the size of the widget can change programmatically (subwidgets are added and removed).  But the user should not be able to resize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
    MyWidget* wgt = new MyWidget(ui->mdiArea); 
    QMdiSubWindow* subWindow = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(wgt); 
    subWindow->setFixedSize(wgt->size());
    wgt->show();
```

Comment: Alright, I hadn't wanted to use `setFixedSize` (see original post) but I guess this, and re-calling it everytime a widget is added or removed, is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `MyWidget` is not resizeable, when you call:

```
ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(wgt);
```

The widget is put in a [`QMdiSubWindow`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmdisubwindow.html) which *is* resizeable. All you have to do is get the window that's created and fix its size:

```
QMdiSubWindow* subWindow = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(wgt);
subWindow->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```

This should work, but I haven't tried this code myself.

EDIT: well... apparently that *doesn't* fix the size. :(

Comment: Nope, didn't change anything.  Definitely seemed like a good try but then again, since `setSizePolicy` is already a method of `QWidget` and not particular to `QMdiSubWindow`.  But upvote for pointing out that `addSubWindow` returns a `QMdiSubWindow*`, I didn't realize that. :)

Comment: Damn. Could you check what the `sizeHint()` method returns for your widget and the subwindow? In particular if the `QSize`s that are return are valid. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsize.html#isValid
 If any are invalid, it might explain why fixing the size policy wouldn't work...